# Autowiring the bean

Tags: spring

I am new to spring and i have a question on autowiring the bean

So basically in my context file i have defined a bean called

```
<bean id="offerpricedao" class="com.impl.OfferPriceDAOImpl" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="offerpriceclass"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="myrole"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2"><null/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And every other bean i have defined here which are referring ..
This code is in src main java..
and in src main test i have a testng test which loads this configuration file and in my test
i have some thing like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:Context.xml" })
public class SetOfferPricesTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {



     @Autowired
      IOfferPriceDAO test;
}
```

and this autowiring works fine ...
I thought we should have this in my configuration file for autowire work..

with out this how my autowiring is working..?

Answer (score 0):

You might be having something like `default-autowire="byName"` in context xml. When you add `@Autowired` Spring finds the implementation of that interface and autowires it. In your case the implementation is `com.impl.OfferPriceDAOImpl`

Also the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation loads the context xml from the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Above config and code is not enough to say how it works.

Since it Works,so the bean is **defined some where** in the **Context.xml** or in the xml files imported in context.xml.

And what dhanush said is also true.